# Сss параллакс и переходы по якорям не работают одновременно

Tags: html, jquery, css, href, parallax

Привет!
По этому примеру написала css стили для параллакс эффекта - http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/demo3/

Но не получается добавить переход по навигационным якорям, например, как тут - http://chriswojcik.net/demos/single-page-nav/

Без параллакса (при `max-width tablet`), плавный скролл работает, когда в силу вступает `media` с параллаксом, переход к якорю не срабатывает.

Код представлен ниже.

**CSS:**

```
.parallax

  @media (min-width tablet)
    perspective: 300px;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;

.parallax__layer
  position relative

  @media (min-width tablet)
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

.parallax__group

  @media (min-width tablet)
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    height 100%
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 0.5s;

.parallax__layer--base

  @media (min-width tablet)
    transform: translateZ(0);
    z-index: 4;

.parallax__layer.parallax__layer--base.right-col

  @media (min-width tablet)
    transform: translateZ(0);

.parallax__layer--back

 @media (min-width tablet)
    transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
    z-index: 3;

.parallax__layer--fore

  @media (min-width tablet)
    transform: translateZ(150px) scale(.5);
    z-index: 1;
```

**JS:**

```
$(".single-page-nav").on("click","a", function (event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  var id  = $(this).attr('href'),

      top = $(id).offset().top;

  if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 450px)").matches) {

      $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top - 110}, 1500);

  }else{

      $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top - 80}, 1500);

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

у каждого блока div должен быть уникальный id(`<div id="id блока на который нужно перейти">`), а ссылка должна быть вида `<a href="#id блока на который нужно перейти">`.

Comment: Ага, конечно, id есть, еще раз напишу, может быть не заметили, что "без параллакса (при max-width tablet), плавный скролл работает, когда в силу вступает media с параллаксом, переход к якорю не срабатывает".

Comment: @ВероникаБыкова попробуйте обернуть все в `<div class="wrapper">` а ему в css задать `height: 100vh;`

Comment: обертка .parallax с height: 100vh; уже есть

Comment: @ВероникаБыкова попробуйте просто c JQuery добавлять к текущей позиции или отнимать 100vh

Comment: ThusMad Спасибо большое за помощь!